# The differential structure of infinite Mobius strip

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

As the title,how to solve the following problem:

**Problem:** Consider the cylinder 
$$
C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2=1\}
$$
and identify the point $(x,y,z)$ with $(-x,-y,-z)$.Show that the quotient space of $C$ by this equivalence relation can be given a differentiable structure (infinite Mobius band).

Please give me more details,thanks!

Comment: Hello, do you know what they mean when they ask for a differentiable structure?

Comment: Yes, of course !

Comment: Why don't you add to your question the meaning of "can be given a differentiable structure" (there are multiple (equivalent) definitions, and it'd be nice for us to know which one you're using). Then you can say how far you've gotten in making this meaning match your situation. And **then** maybe we can help.